# kendo ui grid attributes

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm reading an Angularjs Kendo UI application and I'm trying to figure out what's happening.

In the following code:

```
<div id="my-grid">
  <div kendo-grid="controllerName.myGrid" 
       k-options="controllerName.myGridConfig">
   </div>
 </div>
```

It's obvious from the documentation what k-options stands for but I can't find anything related to kendo-grid attribute.

Comment: I don't use Kendo UI, but this is clearly a directive to create the Kendo Grid Widget: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-creation-in-angularjs

Comment: And what does it take as a value ?

Answer (score 0):

Per the Kendo UI Angular documentation here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-creation-in-angularjs:

> The directives kick in on attributes like kendo-widget-name.

Therefore, the `kendo-grid` attribute will create a Kendo UI Grid widget.

A little further down the page, the section *Widget Options in HTML* says:

> You can specify any options supported by Kendo UI widgets in element attributes by converting the option name from camelCase to dash-separated-words, and prefixing it with k-.

So to configure the Kendo UI grid, you will likely need to set the specific grid attributes using the `k-[attr-name]` syntax.

There are examples for creating widgets and setting properties on that page, and while they don't specifically use the Grid as an example widget, the same principals will apply for creating and configuring your Grid widget.